# Category of binomial rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, binomial-coefficients

A *binomial ring* is a commutative ring $R$ such that (1) the additive group of $R$ is torsionfree and (2) $n!$ divides $x(x-1)\dotsc(x-n+1)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in R$. We may then define $\binom{x}{n} := \frac{x(x-1)\dotsc(x-n+1)}{n!}$ as usual. Jesse Elliott has proven [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404905002161) that a commutative ring is a quotient of a binomial ring if and only if (2) is satisfied. He calls these rings *quasi-binomial*.

I think that the concrete category $\mathsf{BRing}$ of binomial rings is not algebraic, i.e. up to equivalence the category of models of an algebraic theory. Likewise, the larger category $\mathsf{QBRing}$ of quasi-binomial rings is probably not algebraic. But how to prove this? Both categories are complete and cocomplete.

Comment: Are these classes closed under taking subalgebras?

Comment: They are not. However, I am not sure if this is a property of a concrete category.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Birkhoff's HSP theorem? The direction you'd be interested in is very easy.
I'm not sure if you can use it to show that these categories aren't equivalent to an algebraic category, but it does show that BRing isn't algebraic in an obvious way unless it's the same thing as QBRing.

Comment: What does "algebraic in an obvious way" precisely mean?

Comment: That there can't be an algebraic theory such that the class of binomial rings is it's class of models and that homomorphisms are exactly the ring homomorphisms. If such a theory existed, every image of a binomial ring would also be a binomial ring. The problem with this classical approach is that it's supposed to start with a fixed signature to define what H, S and P are, but I think your choice of morphisms also determines them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathsf{BRing}$ *is* algebraic, believe it or not! All the hard work to show this is done in Jesse Elliott's [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404905002161).

In fact, $\mathsf{BRing}$ is reflective and coreflective in $\mathsf{Ring}$ according to the paper (section 7), and it follows that it is closed in $\mathsf{Ring}$ under limits and colimits.

The paper also shows that the obvious forgetful functor $\mathsf{BRing} \to \mathsf{Set}$ has a left adjoint, sending a set $X$ to the ring of integer-valued polynomials with variables in $X$.

So we can apply the monadicity theorem: the forgetful functor $U: \mathsf{BRing} \to \mathsf{Set}$ has a left adjoint and reflects isomorphisms, so we just need to show it creates coequalizers of $U$-split pairs. This is true because the coequalizer of a $U$-split pair exists in $\mathsf{Ring}$, and $\mathsf{BRing}$ is closed under coequalizers.

This stands in stark contrast to torsion-free abelian groups, or torsion-free rings, both of which fail to be exact because they don't contain the quotient $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n$. It's actually very remarkable that $\mathsf{BRing}$ is closed under coequalizers in $\mathsf{Ring}$, and that no torsion can be created modding out by a binomially-closed congruence!

To be explicit: an operation in this algebraic theory is given by an integer-valued polynomial. Generators and relations for this can be found in the paper. It is *not* the theory freely generated by ring operations and operations $\binom{-}{n}$ satisfying $n!\binom{x}{n} = x(x-1)\cdots (x-n+1)$: there are further relations (I'm not sure if these are just the "obvious" ones like the one mentioned in item 2 below).

---

To document my wrong answers so far:

1. I attempted to give a finite-product - coproduct sketch for $\mathsf{BRing}$ to show it was multialgebraic and hence algebraic, but ended up sketching binomial rings and injective homomorphisms, a different category. Thanks to [Zhen Lin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317872/do-torsionfree-abelian-groups-form-a-possibly-many-sorted-algebraic-category) for pointing this out!
2. I attempted to show that the strongly finitely presentable objects of $\mathsf{BRing}$ were the same as those in the full supercategory $\operatorname{Mod}(\mathcal{BR})$ of rings equipped with unary operations $\binom{-}{n}$ subject to $n!\binom{x}{n} = x(x-1)\cdots (x-n+1)$, which would mean $\mathsf{BRing}$ was not the category of models of the only possible Lawvere theory, and hence not algebraic. It turns out that this is wrong because the free objects of $\operatorname{Mod}(\mathcal{BR})$ don't even lie in $\mathsf{BRing}$ -- they have torsion! For instance, in $\operatorname{Mod}(\mathcal{BR})$, the equation $2\binom{x}{2}(x-2) = 6 \binom{x}{3}$ holds, but $\binom{x}{2}(x-2) \neq 3\binom{x}{3}$ does not, as evidenced by $\mathbb{Z}/2$, where the $\binom{-}{n}$ functions can be arbitrary and it's easy to violate this equation.
3. I attempted to show that $\mathsf{BRing}$ was not exact and hence not algebraic, by exhibiting a certain congruence with an exact quotient in $\operatorname{Mod}(\mathcal{BR})$ but not in $\mathsf{BRing}$. This was wrong because the quotient was of the free algebra in $\operatorname{Mod}(\mathcal{BR})$ on two generators, which doesn't lie in $\mathsf{BRing}$. In fact, since exactness is formulated entirely in terms of limits and colimits, the fact that $\mathsf{BRing}$ is closed in $\mathsf{Ring}$ under limits and colimits immediately implies that $\mathsf{BRing}$ inherits exactness from $\mathsf{Ring}$. More about this at a [question I asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323043/binomial-rings-closed-under-colimits) about it.

---

**Update**

Martin quite sensibly asks for generators and relations in the comments. After asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342384/expand-binomxyn-in-terms-of-binomxks-and-binomyks) (and Martin's answer!), I believe that a full set of relations is given by the (special) [$\lambda$-ring relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9B-ring) (with $\lambda^n(x) = \binom{x}{n}$), along with the identity shown [by Darij Grinberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342384/expand-binomxyn-in-terms-of-binomxks-and-binomyks#comment2733723_1342445) (with a slight typo; see his subsequent comment for a link to a proof) $\binom{x}{a}\binom{x}{b} = \sum_{i=a}^{a+b} \binom{i}{a}\binom{a}{a+b-i}\binom{x}{i}$, and of course the identity $n!\binom{x}{n} = x(x-1)\cdots (x-n+1)$. One can check, for example, that the relation $(x-n)\binom{x}{n} = (n+1)\binom{x}{n+1}$, as alluded to in item (2) above, follows from these relations.

**Update Again**
Here's an argument that there's no 2-torsion: if $2x=0$, then $0=\binom{2x}{2}$ (in fact, the binomial operation applied to any integer must yield the usual result, being determined inductively by the addition rule for $\lambda$-rings (the Vandermonde identity)). This can be expanded using the multiplication rule as $4\binom{x}{2} + x$, and the first term is 0 using the rule $2\binom{x}{2} = x(x-1)$. With close study of these relations, I imagine such an analysis could be extended to show there's no torsion at all.

Comment: Thank you. So how does the algebraic theory look like explicitly? If there is one, I suspect that there is a more direct proof. (For me an algebraic theory is just a bunch of function symbols together with a bunch of equations between the derived operations; I find this way more intuitive and practical than Lawvere theories.)

Comment: That's a good question, and I won't totally believe anything I've written above until it's worked out. For a start, a similar argument shows that the torsionfree rings and the torisionfree abelian groups each form varieties, which is equally surprising. Maybe it's easier to figure out what those theories look like first. One caveat is that the default notion of variety here is a _multisorted_ variety.

Comment: Surprising! The torsionfree abelian groups are the subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces. This should give us a two-sorted algebraic theory? Actually I was interested in single-sorted algebraic theories, but let's ignore this.

Comment: The (possibly multisorted) Lawvere theory associated to a variety can be identified as the subcategory of objects $X$ such that $\mathrm{Hom}(X,-)$ preserves sifted colimits, or equivalently preserves filtered colimits and reflexive coequalizers. So the natural first step is to understand how colimits are formed in the category in order to identify these objects. This could be done by unwinding the proof that a complete accessible category is cocomplete, but perhaps it can also be done directly...

Comment: @Martin I'm not sure how to do the axiomatization along those lines algebraically: we can say that $X \to X'$ (where $X'$ is meant to be $\mathbb{Q} \otimes X$) is injective with an equalizer diagram (which is at least _essentially_ algebraic), but I'm not sure how to say that it is an epimorphism algebraically. An essentially algebraic way to state torsionfreeness is to say that the equalizer of $0,n: X \stackrel{\to}{\to} X$ is $0$. But I'm not sure about an algebraic way. I might be inclined to ask this as another question either here or on MO, if you don't beat me to it.

Comment: Please go ahead.

Comment: At last an argument that is clear and straightforward, and that I can believe in!

Comment: Where can I find the relations of the algebraic theory?

Comment: Jessie Elliott gives generators and relations, but with different generators than the $\binom{x}{n}$, so I don't know how to do it with these generators, although I suspect you just need to add all the relations that follow from torsionfreeness. Jessie Elliott's reference for these things seems to be [this book](http://www.ams.org/books/surv/048/).

Answer (score 0):

$\mathsf{QBRing}$ is not algebraic via the usual forgetful functor, because limits in $\mathsf{QBRing}$ are formed by taking the limit in $\mathsf{Ring}$ and then coreflecting into $\mathsf{QBRing}$, so the usual forgetful functor doesn't preserve limits. For instance, in $\mathsf{QBRing}$ the kernel pair of the quotient $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2$ is the identity span, so the pullback given by the kernel pair is not preserved by the usual forgetful functor.

I suspect that $\mathsf{QBRing}$ is not algebraic, or even regular. Its regular epis are a proper subset of those maps which become regular epis in $\mathsf{Ring}$: for example, $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2$ is not regular. But I have not been able to find an example of a pullback of a regular epi which is not regular.

On the other hand, I believe that $\mathsf{QBRing}$ is locally presentable: it can be described as the subcategory of $\mathsf{Ring}$ whose objects are injective with respect to the maps $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[x,y]/n!y = x(x-1)\cdots(x-n+1)$ for each $n$, and small- injectivity classes in locally presentable categories are accessible; it's also (co)complete, so it's locally presentable. I don't know what the degree of accessibility is - it would be interesting to give an essentially algebraic presentation of the category.