# Do torsionfree abelian groups form a (possibly many-sorted) algebraic category?

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra

By "(possibly many-sorted) algebraic category", I mean "category of models of a (possibly many sorted) Lawvere theory. I have arguments for both affirmative and negative answers, and I can't find a hole in either of them. Let $\mathsf{TF}$ denote the category of torsionfree abelian groups.

For background, though, note that $\mathsf{TF}$ is locally finitely presentable: it admits a finite-limit sketch given by adjoining to the sketch for abelian groups with carrier object $X$ the condition that the equalizer of $0, n: X \overset{\to}{\to} X$ is $0$ (where $0$ is the zero map, and $n$ is the multiply-by-$n$ map).

- Here's an abstract argument that $\mathsf{TF}$ *is* algebraic. $\mathsf{TF}$ can be sketched by a finite-product / coproduct sketch (**EDIT**: Zhen Lin points out that this is the mistake!): adjoin to the sketch for abelian groups with carrier object $X$ an object $Y$ and a coproduct diagram $X^0 \overset{0}{\to} X \overset{i}{\leftarrow} Y$, so that $Y$ consists of the nonzero elements of the group; adjoin also arrows $Y \overset{n}{\to} Y$ along with commuting squares of the form

  $\matrix{X & \overset{n}{\to} & X \\
           i \uparrow & & i \uparrow \\
           Y & \overset{n}{\to} & Y}$

  where $i: Y \to X$ is the coproduct injection, $n: Y \to Y$ is the new map, and $n: X \to X$ is multiplication by $n$.

  [This paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404901000159) shows (Lemma 3.1) that any category sketchable by a finite-product / coproduct sketch is multialgebraic, so $\mathsf{TF}$ is multialgebraic. And since any cocomplete multialgebraic category is algebraic (a cocomplete category has multicolimits, [this paper](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/8/n3/8-03abs.html) shows (Theorem 4.4) that a multicocomplete multialgebraic category is a generalized variety and (Theorem 3.10) that a cocomplete generalized variety is a variety, where here "variety" means "algebraic category"), it follows that $\mathsf{TF}$ is algebraic.
- Here's a concrete argument that $\mathsf{TF}$ *is not* algebraic. The finitely-presentable objects of $\mathsf{TF}$ are just the finitely-presentable groups which are torsion-free, i.e. the finitely-generated free abelian groups. This is because $\mathsf{TF}$ is closed in $\mathsf{Ab}$ under filtered colimits, so the same argument as in $\mathsf{Ab}$ shows that the finitely-presentable objects of $\mathsf{TF}$ are finitely-generated in the usual sense (every object $X$ is a filtered colimit of its finitely-generated subobjects, which are torsion-free if $X$ is, so $\mathrm{id}_X$ must factor through one of these subobjects if $\mathrm{Hom}(X,-)$ preserves this filtered colimit).

  The Lawvere theory of an algebraic theory can be recovered (up to Cauchy completion) as the category of strongly finitely-presentable objects (objects $X$ such that $\mathrm{Hom}(X,-)$ preserves sifted colimits, i.e. preserves filtered colimits and reflexive coequalizers), which is a full subcategory of the finitely-presentable objects, closed under finite coproducts and splitting of idempotents. But the only such subcategories of the finitely-generated free abelian groups are (a.) the category consisting of the zero group and (b.) all the finitely-generated free abelian groups. But in the former case, the associated category of algebras is the terminal category while in the latter case it is just $\mathsf{Ab}$ -- so we can't get $\mathsf{TF}$.

So I'm left scratching my head. Which conclusion is correct? Is either argument correct? The step that feels like magic to me is the deduction that the category of models of a finite-product / coproduct sketch is multialgebraic (after all, a finitely sketchable category need not be finitely accessible), but it looks pretty straightforward in the linked paper.

I should mention that this question grew out of my attempt to answer [a question of Martin Brandenburg](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312610/category-of-binomial-rings), which is related, and which I'm still interested in resolving.

**EDIT** So in light of Zhen Lin's comment-answer, what we can conclude is that the category of torsionfree abelian groups and *all* homormophisms is locally finitely presentable (by the first sketch), and the category of torsionfree abelian groups and *injective* homomorphisms is multialgebraic (by the second sketch) -- and hence it's a generalized variety. But the former category is *not* algebraic, and the latter category is *not* complete.

Comment: Why is TF cocomplete?

Comment: Two arguments: I gave a finite-limit sketch for it in the second paragraph, so it's locally finitely presentable. Also, it's a full, reflective subcategory of $\mathsf{Ab}$ (mod out by the torsion subgroup), so the colimit can be formed in $\mathsf{Ab}$ and reflected back into $\mathsf{TF}$.

Comment: Got it. Anyway, I certainly believe your second argument more than your first, especially since the first one refers to three external lemmas / theorems. Have you checked that all of the definitions match up?

Comment: The two papers I cite are by the same authors, and the latter refers to the former, so I think the definitions are consistent (I was worried that the sketchability concept might be ambiguous, but it seems to be consistent). Theorem 5.9 [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404902001263) even extends the sketchability $\to$ multialgebricity and multialgebricity $\to$ generalized variety steps to the generality of a sound limit doctrine, and the generalized variety $\to$ variety step is true almost by definition. It just keeps staying weird...

Comment: Okay, I think the step I'm most suspicious of in the first argument is the claim that TF admits a finite product-coproduct sketch. I don't understand why the thing you've written down is such a sketch. How does introducing $Y$ allow you to state the torsion-free condition?

Comment: @tcamps The homomorphisms of models of your sketch will have to preserve the $\{ 0 \} \amalg Y$ decomposition, so in particular they will be injective. So you are talking about two different categories of torsionfree abelian groups here.

Comment: That would do it! Thanks, Zhen Lin!

Comment: @Qiaochu I added a few words and a diagram to try to clarify this.

Comment: Why are answers given in comments???