# Expand $\binom{xy}{n}$ in terms of $\binom{x}{k}$'s and $\binom{y}{k}$'s

Tags: combinatorics, ring-theory, category-theory

Motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312610/category-of-binomial-rings/), I want to find a complete set of relations for the ring of integer-valued polynomials, where the generators are the polynomials $\binom{x}{n}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. The best way to do this is would be to describe how to decompose $\binom{x+y}{n}$ and $\binom{xy}{n}$ as a sum of products of $\binom{x}{0},\dots, \binom{x}{n}$ and $\binom{y}{0},\dots,\binom{y}{n}$. This can be done in principle by peeling off the binomials starting with the highest degree and working one's way down. Playing around with Sage, one soon guesses that

$\binom{x+y}{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{x}{k}\binom{y}{n-k}$

and in fact, I think this has a combinatorial proof which straightforwardly generalizes that of the identity $\binom{m}{n} = \binom{m}{n-1} + \binom{m-1}{n-1}$.

But $\binom{xy}{n}$ seems to be not so straightforward. The first few expansions are:

$\binom{xy}{2} = 2\binom{x}{2}\binom{y}{2} + x\binom{y}{2} + y \binom{x}{2}$

$\binom{xy}{3} = 6\binom{x}{3} \binom{y}{3} + $

$\qquad ~ ~ 6 \binom{x}{3}\binom{y}{2} + 6\binom{x}{2}\binom{y}{3} + $

$\qquad ~ ~ x \binom{y}{3} + 4 \binom{x}{2} \binom{y}{2} + y \binom{x}{3}  $

$\binom{xy}{4} = 24\binom{x}{4}\binom{y}{4} + $

$\qquad ~ ~ 36\binom{x}{3}\binom{y}{4} + 36 \binom{x}{4}\binom{y}{3} + $

$ \qquad ~ ~ 14 \binom{x}{2}\binom{y}{4} + 45\binom{x}{3}\binom{y}{3} + 14 \binom{x}{4}\binom{y}{2} + $

$\qquad ~ ~ 12 \binom{x}{2}\binom{y}{3} + 12 \binom{x}{3}\binom{y}{2} + $

$\qquad ~ ~ \binom{x}{2}\binom{y}{2}$

and it is not so easy to discern a pattern.

This must be well-known: what is a closed-form expression for the expansion of $\binom{xy}{n}$?

Comment: Does computing the coefficients of $(a+b)^{xy} = ((a+b)^x)^y$ yield anything? (Maybe that's how you computed these first terms?)

Comment: Your addition identity is known as [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).  The multiplication is an interesting question, but I should note that I'm not sure it does what you want -- if you want relations, wouldn't it make more sense to decompose $\binom{x}{n}\binom{x}{m}$ as a sum of $\binom{x}{k}$?  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: I think that the link in the question is wrong.

Comment: Link fixed, thanks. I guess I just linked to something random that I had open in my browser!

Comment: @HarryAltman Thanks for the reference, and you're right, I need to look at $\binom{x}{n}\binom{x}{m}$, too, although $\binom{xy}{n}$ is also necessary. I also need to look at $\binom{\binom{x}{n}}{m}$ for my ultimate purposes, which involve understanding all the relations when $\binom{-}{n}$ is considered as another operation like addition and multiplication.

Comment: You probably already know this, but Vandermonde's identity gives rise to a recursive formula: $$\binom{x(y+1)}{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{xy}{k} \binom{x}{n-k}$$ You could play with that and see if anything fun pops out -- in fact, the result will be solely in terms of the $\binom{x}{m}$ and (powers of) $y$. But I imagine you won't get much better than Martin's answer.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, iterating this formula yields something like $$\binom{xy}{n} = \sum_{k_1=0}^n \sum_{k_2=0}^{k_1} \cdots \sum_{k_{y-1}=0}^{k_{y-2}} \binom{x}{n-k_1} \binom{x}{n-k_2} \cdots \binom{x}{n-k_{y-1}} \binom{x}{k_{y-1}}$$ Do with this what you will... I'll let you decide if this is sufficiently "closed" for you :P

Comment: Thanks, Clive, I did not know any of this! Missed you at the CT this year, by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The identity $\binom{x+y}{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{x}{k} \binom{y}{n-k}$ is well-known, it is called the [Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity). The answer for $\binom{xy}{n}$ can be explained using the notion of a [$\lambda$-ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9B-ring), where here we consider the [binomial ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_ring) $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\lambda^n(x)=\binom{x}{n}$. The main theorem on symmetric polynomials enables us to write
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} P_k(\sigma_1,\dotsc,\sigma_k,\tau_1,\dotsc,\tau_k) \,t^k = \prod_{i,j=1}^{n} (1+ t x_i y_j)$$
for some polynomials $P_k \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dotsc,x_k,y_1,\dotsc,y_k]$, where $\sigma_1,\dotsc,\sigma_n$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials in $x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n$ and $\tau_1,\dotsc,\tau_n$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials in $y_1,\dotsc,y_n$. Then, one has  (by definition) $$\lambda^n(xy)=P_n\bigl(\lambda^1(x),\dotsc,\lambda^n(x),\lambda^1(y),\dotsc,\lambda^n(y)\bigr).$$
For example:
$$\lambda^2(xy) = x^2 \lambda^2(y) + \lambda^2(x) y^2 - 2 \lambda^2(x) \lambda^2(y)$$
$$\lambda^3(xy)=x^3 \lambda^3(y) + \lambda^3(x) y^3 + x \lambda^2(x) y \lambda^2(y) - 3 x \lambda^2(x) \lambda^3(y) - 3 \lambda^3(x) y \lambda^2(y) + 3 \lambda^3(x) \lambda^3(y)$$
Of course, one has to prove that every binomial ring becomes a $\lambda$-ring. See for instance  Darij Grinberg's [notes](https://sites.google.com/site/darijgrinberg/lambda), Theorem 7.2 (which is a corollary of Theorem 7.1).

Comment: Interesting. From the looks of things, special $\lambda$-rings have all the necessary relations to reduce binomial ring expression in variables $x_1,\dots, x_n$ to the form $\sum_k \binom{x_1}{m_1}\cdots \binom{x_n}{m_n}$ _except_ for a rule on how to reduce $\binom{x}{i}\binom{x}{j}$. I think if that expansion is worked out, it will compelete the list of relations that hold for binomial rings.

Comment: See my edit for the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$, which differ from your relations. Notice that the Adams operations of binomial rings are trivial, which explains that binomial rings satisfy more relations than $\lambda$-rings.

Comment: Interesting. It's not at all obvious how to construct these particular relations. But I did at least check the $n=2$ case, and verified that the $\lambda$-equation and the equation are equivalent in any ring where $2\binom{x}{2} = x(x-1)$ (and similarly for $y$) holds.

Comment: after messing around with Sage a bit more, I think the missing relation is $\binom{x}{m}\binom{x}{n} = \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k}\binom{n+k}{m}\binom{x}{k}$, a strangely asymmetric formula. I certainly haven't proven this, though, and I don't know where to find out more about it.

Comment: Instructive answer and interesting reference. +1

Comment: @tcamps: Something is broken about your formula, as the sum must definitely go beyond $k=m$ for degree reasons. But now that you mention this, I think there is a closed formula for the $e_i$ in Exercise 4 of http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/primes2015/sol1.pdf akin to your formula.

Comment: Actually, yes: $\dbinom{x}{a}\dbinom{x}{b} = \sum\limits_{i=a}^{a+b} \dbinom{i}{a}\dbinom{a}{a+b-i}\dbinom{x}{a}$. The right hand side looks asymmetric in $a$ and $b$, but is actually symmetric.

Comment: I have updated http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/primes2015/sol1.pdf . There are now two solutions of Exercise 4, the second of which proves this identity. (And there is a remark showing that the two solutions are equivalent.) Thanks @tcamps for making me see this problem from a new angle!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out; I think $\binom{x}{a}$ should be $\binom{x}{i}$ in your formula?

Comment: Also, I should point out that in order to form a complete set of relations for binomial rings, in addition to this multiplication formula and the $\lambda$-ring formulas, as far as I can tell we still need to explicitly include the formula $n!\binom{x}{n} = x(x-1)\cdots (x-n+1)$, in order to convert the $\lambda$-ring formulas to "pure binomial" formulas as in your response, @darijgrinberg.

Answer (score 3):

[A beautiful combinatorial answer](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h299793p1623722) was found by Gjergji Zajmi. For an expanded version, see the solution to Exercise 3.9 in my [*Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/primes2015/sols.pdf). (At least, it is Exercise 3.9 in [the version of 10 January 2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10). In future versions, the numbering can shift.)

Unlike Martin's answer, this one directly gives a formula for $\dbinom{xy}{n}$ as a nonnegative linear combination of products $\dbinom{x}{k}\dbinom{y}{\ell}$, as opposed to a polynomial in the $\dbinom{x}{k}$ and the $\dbinom{y}{\ell}$. This, of course, does not work for arbitrary $\lambda$-rings.

Comment: Of course! It's so simple once you see it! Thanks. I wonder if there's any more that can be said about these coefficients -- the number of $\mathbb{F}_2$-matrices of given dimensions with exactly $n$ 1's and every row and column occupied...

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Nice reference! +1

Answer (score 1):

There's another formula for the expression in equation (3) on the bottom of page 183 of my paper here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404905002161

The formula is ${{xy} \choose n} = \underset{l_1 + 2 l_2 + \cdots + nl_n = n}{\sum}  {{\sum_{i=1}^n l_i} \choose {l_1, l_2, \ldots, l_n}} {y \choose {\sum_{i=1}^n l_i}} \prod_{i=1}^n {x \choose l_i}$, proved by expanding $(1+T)^{xy} = ((1+T)^x)^y$ using the binomial and multinomial theorems.