# Product of two binomial coefficients in terms of linear combinations of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

For $n,a,b$ natural numbers with $a+b \leq n$, can we find **positive** rational numbers $c_1, \ldots, c_{a+b}$ such that
$$
{n \choose a}{n \choose b} = \sum_{k=1}^{a+b}c_k{n \choose k}?
$$
Is there a formula?

Here are three examples with $n = 5$:
\begin{align*}
{5 \choose 1}{5 \choose 1} &= {5 \choose 1} + 2 {5 \choose 2};\\
{5 \choose 1}{5 \choose 3} &= {5 \choose 1} + {5 \choose 2} + \dfrac{3}{2}{5 \choose 3} + 4 {5 \choose 4};\\
{5 \choose 2}{5 \choose 3}&= 3{5 \choose 1} + 3 {5 \choose 2} + 3{5 \choose 3} + 3{5 \choose 4} + 10{5 \choose 5}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Are these also positive?

Comment: See Proposition 3.7 (if the numbering changes, search for "junction" in the chapter on binomial coefficients) in http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/primes2015/sols.pdf . The first proof gives a combinatorial expression for the $c_k$ (which I call $e_k$), while the second proof gives an algebraic formula; Remark 3.8 briefly explains why the two results are the same. (The second proof, in turn, originates in a comment on m.se, at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342384 .)

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is a duplicate. The identity given there expresses the product of the binomial coefficients ${x \choose i}{x \choose j}$ in terms of binomial coefficients ${x \choose i + j - k}$ for $k$ only up to $i$. I however asked for an expression with the indices up to $i+k$ with the $c_k$ positive, assuming $i + j \leq x$. Darij's link, and that given by Jack, show that in general one may have to be satisfied with a few of these coefficients being zero. However, again, in the special case when $i + j \leq x$, could we show or not these coefficients are all strictly positive?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question, but it seems that the existence of such $c_k$ would imply that $\binom{n}{a}\binom{n}{b}$ is dependent only on $n$ and $a+b$. However, $\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{2}=24$ and $\binom{4}{0}\binom{4}{3}=4$.

Comment: Actually, I realized the question maybe a bit silly, since one can always find such small or large enough positive constants. Thus a formula, rather than existence, is more of the goal.

Comment: @user152169: The rational numbers $c_k$ that satisfy $\dbinom{n}{a}\dbinom{n}{b} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k \dbinom{n}{k}$ *for all sufficiently high $n$* are uniquely determined. Thus, you cannot force the ones with $k < \max\left\{a,b\right\}$ to be positive.